# AS2 FP8: HTTPS SWF loading data from HTTP

Tags: flash, security, https, actionscript-2

I have an AS2 FP8 swf hosted on an HTTPS site that needs to sendAndLoad data to a HTTP site. I've read the whitepaper covering crossdomain policy files, yet they only cover the scenario of a HTTP swf loading data from HTTPS and not vice versa.

For the time being the crossdomain policy is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM http://www.adobe.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd"><cross-domain-policy>
<site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all"/>
<allow-access-from domain="*" secure="false"/>
<allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*" secure="false"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Is it because of secure being to set to false?

Comment: Are you saying that you can't communicate from a SWF loaded from a secure (https) site to data sources located on http?  Your question isn't very clear.

Comment: does it work when you load from a http server (not the same host as your swf)? have you tried looking into firebug net panel or such to see if the crossdomain.xml is being found?

Answer (score 0):

The `secure=false` is equivalent to the following property:

- [AllowInsecureDomain](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/2/00001491.html)

An HTTPS swf loading data from a HTTP is not recommended for the following reason:

> The restriction on HTTP-to-HTTPS scripting is asymmetrical; although an HTTP-delivered catalog.swf file cannot safely be allowed to script an HTTPS-delivered cart.swf file, an HTTPS cart.swf file may script the HTTP catalog.swf file.